# SQLite QUERY optimization (join with equal vs not equal)

Tags: sql, sqlite

This query works relatively quickly

`SELECT count(*) FROM master m INNER JOIN slave s ON m.file = s.file WHERE m.size <>  s.size;`

This query seems to never finish

`SELECT count(*) FROM master m INNER JOIN slave s ON m.file = s.file WHERE m.size = s.size;`

There are indexes on the fields file and size.
There are about 1.5 million records in both tables.

the 1st query finishes quickly. The 2nd query seems to never finish. (I give up after 30 minutes)

Why? How can I optimize it?  explain query plan wasn't much help.

Comment: Good observations but you seem to have forgotten to ask a question.  Please read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this post

Comment: D'oh!  Total brain fart - I know I had the thought in my head, that thought failed to make it thru to my fingers...

Comment: *explain query plan wasn't much help.* - It may be to someone else. Please include it in your post as text.

Comment: "There are indexes on the fields file and size" Combined? Both queries should benefit from these two indexes `create index idxm on master(file, size)` and `create index idxs on slave(file, size)`. But in the end it boils down to how many matches there are. Just to illustrate this: Let's just say all rows in both tables have the same file and size. Then your first query will have no matches and end quickly. The second will have to join 1.5M rows with 1.5M other rows and end up with 2,250,000,000,000 result rows, which may cause severe memory problems.

Comment: Thorsten:  I have tried a combind [master (Files,Size)] and 2 individual indexes [master(file) and size(file); (same for slave)]
Is there a better way to improve that performance?  For now, I did a "create temporary table as ..." for the <> query, then do a select ... not in (select * from ...[temporary table]); that's working, but it's still slow.
You are correct, about 470 records that do not match. the rest match.
Curiously, there are 347 duplicates in there, if I eliminate the duplicates; the queries happen much faster.

Comment: Ken:
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE master (file TEXT, size INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE slave  (file TEXT, size INTEGER);
CREATE INDEX fileM ON master (file);
CREATE INDEX sizeM ON master (size);
CREATE INDEX sizeS ON slave  (size);
sqlite> explain query plan SELECT count(*) FROM master m INNER JOIN slave s ON m.file = s.file WHERE m.size = s.size;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN s
`--SEARCH m USING INDEX fileM (file=?)

Comment: Ken (pt2)
And....

sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE master (file TEXT, size INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE slave  (file TEXT, size INTEGER);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fullM on master (file,size);
sqlite> explain query plan SELECT count(*) FROM master m INNER JOIN slave s ON m.file = s.file WHERE m.size = s.size;
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN s
`--SEARCH m USING COVERING INDEX fullM (file=? AND size=?)